# Linking pairs of numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linked-list

Given a list of paired numbers `[(13, 4), (8, 12), (8, 4), (13, 2)]` where each number appears exactly once or twice, what's a good algorithm to create a "linked list", where tuples are connected if they shared a number?

Linking the above tuples would return either `(2, 13)-(13, 4)-(4, 8)-(8, 12)` or just `(2-13-4-8-12)` (or either the reverse order, the order in a pair doesn't matter).

(As a second question: is there a name for this type of problem?)

Comment: Looks like a graph problem. You're putting edges between nodes based on some condition. Are you guaranteed the links always work out perfectly like this? If so, maybe you could call it a sorting problem.

Comment: So these tuples are actually sets, because I see you are allowed to use them without regard for order, while tuples are usually considered to have [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)

Comment: @ggorlen I will assume that they always work out perfectly. It is kind of a sorting problem, but not really. The reason I asked for a name for the problem ("second question") is that if it has a name, there likely exists an algorithm for it. I can rephrase it to make it clearer.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Now that I think about it more, I'm leaning more towards "graph problem" than "sorting problem", even with the constraint that it works out perfectly. The reason is, in a normal sorting problem, you have transitive relationships, so if you want to sort the pair `15, 2` you can do that, but in this problem, there's no way to sort `(2, 13), (4, 56)` -- you either link them or you don't. That's a graph to me even if it's a degenerate graph that's a linked list.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a graph problem, because as soon as you have the graph, you have the solution, you just have to iterate on it. So the name of the problem is to build an undirected graph based on its adjacency list, where the nodes are the numbers, and the given list is actually an adjacency list.

Comment: The head of the list can be any of the two vertices with degree == 1. Such graphs are called path graph, or linear graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the input defines a graph that is a single path, you could use this algorithm. I used Python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# The function that takes a list of pairs as input and returns the path/chain
def chain(pairs):
    # create graph
    edges = defaultdict(set)  # each node will be associated with a set of neighbors
    for a, b in pairs:
        edges[a].add(b)
        edges[b].add(a)  # define both the forward as backward edge

    # find a node with just one edge
    start = pairs[0][0]  # default node
    for node, second in edges.items():
        if len(second) == 1:
            start = node
            break

    # start at that node and follow the edges
    result = [start]
    prev = None
    while len(result) <= len(pairs):
        neighbors = edges[start]
        neighbors.discard(prev)  # discard the back referencing edge
        prev = start
        start = next(iter(neighbors))  # get the only other neighbor
        result.append(start)
    return result

pairs = [(13, 4), (8, 12), (8, 4), (13, 2)]
print(chain(pairs))
```

Comment: I was hoping for a shorter answer, but after thinking I don't think it can be much better. I will add my answer as well (based on yours).

Answer (score 0):

This is based on trincot's answer, which avoids mutating the graph:

```py
def make_graph(edges):
    graph = defaultdict(set)
    for a, b in pairs:
        edges[a].add(b)
        edges[b].add(a
    return graph

def find_endpoints(edges):
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import chain
    return [v for v, count in Counter(chain(*edges)).items() if count == 1]

def find_path(graph, start, end):
    chain = [start, next(iter(graph[start]))]
    while chain[-1] != end:
        for neighbour in graph[chain[-1]]:
            if neighbour != chain[-2]:
                chain.append(neighbour)
                break
    return chain

edges = [(13, 4), (8, 12), (8, 4), (13, 2)]
graph = make_graph(edges)
endpoints = find_endpoints(edges)
path = find_path(graph, *endpoints)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible implementation which avoids using graphs, and instead joins edges to sub-chains, until they form a single long chains:

```py
def chain(edges):
    from collections import deque
    link = lambda c, e: (c.appendleft if c[0] == a else c.append)
    chains = {}
    for a, b in edges:
        if a in chains and b in chains:
            c1 = chains.pop(a)
            c2 = chains.pop(b)
            if c1[0] == a: c1.reverse()
            if c2[0] != b: c2.reverse()
            c1.extend(c2)
            chains[c1[-1]] = c1
        elif a in chains:
            chain = chains.pop(a)
            link(chain, a)(b)
        elif b in chains:
            chain = chains.pop(b)
            link(chain, b)(a)
        else:
            chains[a] = chains[b] = deque([a, b])

    return set(map(tuple, chains.values())).pop()

edges = [(13, 4), (8, 12), (8, 4), (13, 2)]
path = chain(edges)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it would be of some help to anyone from the JVM world, I've managed to reproduce this algorithm as a Kotlin function.

```
fun chain(pairs: List<Pair<Int, Int>>): MutableList<Int> {
    val edges = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableSet<Int>>()
    pairs.forEach { (a, b) ->
        edges[a] = mutableSetOf()
        edges[b] = mutableSetOf()
    }
    pairs.forEach { (a, b) ->
        edges[a]!!.add(b)
        edges[b]!!.add(a)
    }
    if (pairs.isNotEmpty()) {
        var start = pairs[0].first
        var prev: Int? = null
        for ((node, value) in edges.entries) {
            if (value.size == 1) {
                start = node
                break
            }
        }
        val result = mutableListOf(start)
        while (result.size <= pairs.size) {
            val neighbors = edges[start]
            neighbors?.remove(prev)
            prev = start
            neighbors?.forEach { start = it }
            result.add(start)
        }
        return result
    }
    return mutableListOf()
}
```